# Scale element to proportionally fill space

Tags: css, responsive-design

The example below has an gray div (#outer) with a child orange div (#inner). #inner will fill the page proportionally on **width** only. Is it possible to have #inner scale proportionally based on **width and height** using only CSS? Please, no Javascript solutions as I am aware of how to accomplish it that route, but would prefer a CSS solution if possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gchr4/

CSS

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#outer {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#inner {
    background-color: #ff9933;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript example of what I am attempting to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Qdy/

Comment: Both your fiddles are behaving the same way. Am I missing something??

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore They act similar, but not the same. If you scale the window vertically (very small) you can see how the first Fiddle triggers a scrollbar and the second Fiddle resizes #inner and does not have a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `height:100%` for the `#inner`.
However, due to your padding, the height will add 50% to it. This will be fixed by using `box-sizing:border-box`, but this still has some browser issues. So if you don't have to add padding, i would suggest to remove it.

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gchr4/1/)

```
#inner {
    background-color: #ff9933;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: #inner isn't scaling proportionally. #inner should only ever fill the parent fully if the parent is also the same proportion. Not seeing that functionality here.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? It's a little confusing.

Comment: #inner should scale proportionally to best fill the parent (#outer). Currently, the example I provided only scales proportionally based on the width of #outer. I would like to be able to scale proportionally based on the height and width. For example, if you make resize the window so it is very short, you will see a scrollbar appear; it shouldn't. #inner should scale proportionally so a scrollbar never appears.

Comment: This example is working even if you resize the window. Unless you're trying to resize it by height?...

Comment: @Jason, if you want it to scale proportionately, then set the width and height of the #inner to 100% and get rid of padding-top.  When padding is set as %, it is the % of the width (not height) of the containing parent.

Comment: @DRD I want the scale #inner proportionally. Using padding-top: 50% is intentional as it causes #inner to scale proportionally by width. If width and height are 100%, it will simply fill, not scale proportionally.

Comment: You have to be more precise.  For example, here's a fiddle of the #inner scaling on both width and height relative to the #outer: http://jsfiddle.net/Xw5j3/.  Is this what you are looking for or something else?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Qdy/ I'm seeking a CSS-only solution for this (if one exists). Resize the view area to see how it scales.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using media queries (and min-aspect-ratio, in particular) and viewport units: http://jsfiddle.net/79Fhb/.

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#outer {
    background-color: #bbb;
    height: 100%;
}

#inner {
    background-color: #ff9933;
}

#inner:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 50%;
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1) {
    #inner {
        height: 100%;
        width: 200vmin;
    } 
}
```